# How do I connect via PHP to this complicated WSDL server (payment system from 3delta)?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I am trying to connect to this WSDL server using PHP:

https://services.PWSDemo.com/CreditCardTransactionService.svc?wsdl

I have tried:

```
$client  = new SoapClient('https://services.PWSDemo.com/CreditCardTransactionService.svc?wsdl');

$result = $client->AuthorizeAndCapture( array( 'credentials' => $credentials, 'authorizeAndCaptureParams' => $acparam));
```

Where $credentials is an array like this:

```
$credentials = array(); 
$credentials['ClientCode'] = "XYZOffice"; 
$credentials['UserName'] = "Linxtrans"; 
$credentials['Password'] = "C0de5ample!";
```

And

$acParem is a similar but much more complicated array I am not posting in full for brevity (see below for more)

I also tried with classes such as:

```
class ClientCredentials {
    public $ClientCode;
    public $Password;
    public $UserName;
}
```

Without success, I always get the error: The authorizeAndCaptureParams parameter is required.

In the class example, the acparam is defined this way:

```
class AuthorizeAndCaptureParams {
    public $AddOrUpdateCard;
    public $CreditCardTransaction;
    public $TerminalIdentifier;
    public function __construct(){
        $this->TerminalIdentifier = new TerminalIdentifier();
        $this->CreditCardTransaction= new CreditCardTransaction();
    }
}
```

In the PHP array attempt, I start this way:

```
$acParams['CreditCardTransaction'] = array();
$acParams['CreditCardTransaction']['CreditCard'] = array();
$acParams['CreditCardTransaction']['CreditCard']['Cardholder'] = array(); 
$acParams['CreditCardTransaction']['CreditCard']['Cardholder']['FirstName'] = "John"; 
$acParams['CreditCardTransaction']['CreditCard']['Cardholder']['LastName'] = "Smith"; 
$acParams['CreditCardTransaction']['CreditCard']['BillingAddress'] = array();
```

The company only supplies examples in C# and when asked for PHP support, they reply that PHP is not supported, but "many of their customers implemented their API with PHP".

And so, I am at a loss as to how to proceed....

I have implemented WSDL clients in the past, but with simple data structures, but never with such elaborate data structures!

Comment: Perhaps they can connect you with a customer who has successfully implemented PHP?

Comment: I asked and was told that they couldn't out of "confidentiality"

In short, they even asked why we couldn't do it in C#, as if everyone was on a Windows server...